# Groovy SoapClient Post 500 Error

Tags: soap, groovy

I want to make a soap request with SoapClient in groovy.
My Code:

```
 SoapClient client = SoapClient.builder()
            .endpointUri("http://www.webservicex.com/globalweather.asmx")
            .build();      
 String output = client.post(requestxml)
```

Request XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><soapenv:Envelope   xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soapenv:Header/>
<soapenv:Body>
    <web:GetWeather xmlns:web="http://www.webserviceX.NET">
       <web:CityName>Berlin</web:CityName>
       <web:CountryName>Germany</web:CountryName>
     </web:GetWeather>
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I always get an exception:
ERROR errors.GrailsExceptionResolver  - TransmissionException occurred when processing request:

HTTP response=[Internal Server Error] code=[500]. Stacktrace follows:
Message: HTTP response=[Internal Server Error] code=[500]
    Line | Method
->>  171 | executePost              in org.reficio.ws.client.core.SoapClient

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Which soap client are you using?

Comment: Hi, org.reficio.ws.client.core.SoapClient

Comment: Which is in which library? Also, what version?

Comment: @Peter, I don't know why but the client is sending content with `text/html` content type which causes an error.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using WSLite: http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Ca%3A%22groovy-wslite%22 This is almost standard SOAP client for Groovy, IMHO.